# Plotting two categorical arrays in a histogram/bar chart?

Tags: matlab, plot, bar-chart, matlab-figure, categorical-data

I have a categorical array, race, and an array of yes/no, and I want to somehow create a stacked bar/histogram plot with each race having its own bar and each bar is broken up into two different colors - one for the respondents that said yes, and the others for the ones that said no. Is there any way to do this relatively simply in MATLAB? And is there a way at least create a table that shows for each race, how many said yes, how many said no?

To clarify, there are 1250 rows in my data set, each row representing the responses of a person. I split it up so there is a nominal array called `YESNO` that is 1250x1 nominal. It has `Y` or `N`. I also have a nominal array called `RACE`, which is 1250x1, and has 5 different races chosen.

I would like to somehow make a histogram that looks like this, which I made in Tableau ("yes" is orange, blue is "no"):
[image]

If I can't do this, I would at least like to be able to have a table that shows each race and then how many responded with "yes" and how many with "no".

I've tried to do the following:

```
bar(RACE,YESNO)
```

And I get that the XData values must be unique.

So then I tried doing a histogram of the data:

```
histogram(RACE,YESNO)
```

And I get something that looks like this:

[image]

Which is not at all what I want. I've been looking all over the documentation to see if there's a way to do a stacked bar graph with this categorical data, or at least a stacked histogram, but nothing seems to be able to point me in the right direction. I can't find anything on doing a stacked histogram of categorical data, and `bar` is not allowing me to use my current data to be modelled.

Also, I would be willing to use the [hospital data set](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/dataset-array-columns.html) included in MATLAB to see an example. There is the gender column that can be plotted against smoking in a similar manner.

Is there a way of going about this in MATLAB?

Comment: Could you provide an illustration of what you want to achieve and some sample data? I highly doubt somebody would go through the trouble of generating data to fit your description.

Comment: @Dev-iL, just edited it so that it's clear exactly what I want to do.

Comment: Hi @Adriaan, I definitely did not mean for this to show a lack of effort - in fact, I have exhausted all my resources on the docs. I have included what I have tried and where I'm stuck in my recent edit. I'm new at Matlab so my skills are limited, and I'm looking for someone to point me in the right direction, as there are multiple datasets in which I would like to do something similar to this.

Comment: @Adriaan thank you! I've also included some information on sample data and how that could be used to demonstrate this. I haven't found anything online or on SO that would allow someone to plot categorical data in this way.

Comment: I agree with Adriaan - the question is much better now. Which version of MATLAB are you using?

Comment: @Dev-iL, thank you. I'm using 2016b for Mac, updated September 7th, 2016.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your data looks like this:

```
yesno = categorical(randi(2,1250,1),[1 2],{'no','yes'});
race = categorical(randi(5,1250,1),1:5,{'Asian','Black','BHispanic','White','WHispanic'});
```

You can do the following:

```
% convert everything to numeric:
yn = double(yesno); 
rac = double(race);
% caluculate all frequencies:
data = accumarray([rac yn],1);
% get the categories names:
races = categories(race);   
answers = categories(yesno);
% plotting:
bar(data,0.4,'stacked');
ax = gca;
ax.XTickLabel = races; % set the x-axis ticks to the race names
legend(answers) % add a legend for the colors
colormap(lines(3)) % use nicer colors (close to your example)
ylabel('YES/NO')% set the y-axis lable
% some other minor fixes:
box off
ax.YGrid = 'on';
```

The result:

[image: the bar]

And you can make a table from it with:

```
T = array2table(data.','VariableNames',races,'RowNames',answers)
```

The output:

```
T = 
           Asian    Black    BHispanic    White    WHispanic
           _____    _____    _________    _____    _________
    no     126      123      102          128      144      
    yes    145      126      128          105      123
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! This is exactly what I wanted. My only question is if this can be generalized to have more than yes/no, and have more than 2 in that category. Will the steps be the same exactly?

Comment: I'm actually not sure how you would do this because you take the total and subtract the accumulation of yes for each category to get amount of "no".

Comment: I've posted the follow up question here so it can be found easier by the SO community for any future searchers. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42336322/matlab-working-with-accumarray-with-multiple-categories

Comment: @rb612 I have edited the answer to fit more categories the 2 (yes/no).