# MATLAB - Working with accumarray with multiple categories?

Tags: matlab

I am asking a follow-up my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42312725/plotting-two-categorical-arrays-in-a-histogram-bar-chart), in which there was a perfect solution that did exactly what I wanted. But I'm wondering how to apply this method, or do something similar, if instead of yes/no as possible responses, I would have more than 2 responses, so yes/no/maybe, for example. Or how it would generalize to 3+ responses.

This is the answer, reformatted as my question:

Assuming my data looks like this:

```
responses = categorical(randi(3,1250,1),[1 2 3],{'no','yes','maybe'});
race = categorical(randi(5,1250,1),1:5,{'Asian','Black','BHispanic','White','WHispanic'});
```

I would like to go through and do the same thing with my yes/no data, but do this with 3 possibilities, or more. And this will not end up working anymore:

```
% convert everything to numeric:
yn = double(responses); 
rac = double(race);
% caluculate all frequencies:
data = accumarray(rac,yn-1);
data(:,2) = accumarray(rac,1)-data;
% get the categories names:
races = categories(race);   
answers = categories(responses);
% plotting:
bar(data,0.4,'stacked');
ax = gca;
ax.XTickLabel = races; % set the x-axis ticks to the race names
legend(answers) % add a legend for the colors
colormap(lines(3)) % use nicer colors (close to your example)
ylabel('YES/NO/MAYBE')% set the y-axis label
% some other minor fixes:
box off
ax.YGrid = 'on';
```

I'm not sure if there is even a way to use the accumarray method to do this, as it doesn't make sense from my understanding to use this with 3 possible responses. I'd like to generalize it to n possible responses too.

UPDATE: I'm currently investigating the crosstab feature which I didn't find at all until now! I think this may be the feature I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a generalized version:

```
% the data (with even more categories):
yesno = categorical(randi(4,1250,1),1:4,{'no','yes','maybe','don''t know'});
race = categorical(randi(5,1250,1),1:5,{'Asian','Black','BHispanic','White','WHispanic'});
% convert everything to numeric:
yn = double(yesno); 
rac = double(race);
% caluculate all frequencies:
data = accumarray([rac yn],1);
% get the categories names:
races = categories(race);   
answers = categories(yesno);
% plotting:
bar(data,0.4,'stacked');
ax = gca;
ax.XTickLabel = races; % set the x-axis ticks to the race names
legend(answers) % add a legend for the colors
colormap(lines(numel(answers))) % use pretier colors
ylabel('YES/NO')% set the y-axis lable
% some other minor fixes:
box off
ax.YGrid = 'on';
```

The result:

[image: bar]

And in a table:

```
T = array2table(data.','VariableNames',races,'RowNames',answers)
```

the output:

```
T = 
                  Asian    Black    BHispanic    White    WHispanic
                  _____    _____    _________    _____    _________
    no            58       72       69           66       62       
    yes           58       53       72           54       58       
    maybe         63       62       67           62       61   
    don't know    58       57       66           58       74
```

---

As you already mentioned, you can use `crosstab` for the same task. `crosstab(rac,yn)` will give you the same result as `accumarray([rac yn],1)`. I think `accumarray` is faster, though I didn't check it.